# Go: how to divide huge numbers?

Tags: math, go

I'm new in Golang and my problem is:

I have two byte arrays of 64 elements each, let's name them "A" and "B". Each of those arrays represent an unsigned integer.

I wish to produce another 64-bytes array "R" representing the result of (A / B).

Any ideas?

```
// pre-condition: A and B have 64 bytes each
// A and B each represent an unsigned integer
// R = (A / B)

func divideByteArrays(A, B []byte) []byte {
    R := make([]byte, 64)
    // ... do something ...
    return R
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

is it possible to use "math/big" to achieve that goal ?

Comment: The the [`math/big` package](https://godoc.org/math/big) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Well thanks for the suggestion, but I did indeed take a look at that package but I could not find anything to help me with those byte arrays. As I've seen,  it's possible to reach those huge numbers by slowly doing operations with little numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/T5R8fB8q60

```
package main

import (
    "math/big"
    "fmt"
)

func divideByteArrays(A, B []byte) []byte {
    var AI, BI, R big.Int
    AI.SetBytes(A)
    BI.SetBytes(B)
    R.Div(&AI, &BI)
    return R.Bytes()
}

func main() {
    a_array := make([]byte, 64)
    b_array := make([]byte, 64)

    for i := 0; i < 64; i++ {
        a_array[i] = 4
        b_array[i] = 2
    }

    fmt.Println(divideByteArrays(a_array, b_array))
}
```

Comment: Omg you sir are a genius! I got stuck at this problem for quite a while. Thank you very much.